# WinForms - DataGridViewCell not being set to read only

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on an old .Net 2.0 WinForms project and need to set some cells to read only.

I have a DataTable that I am reading and setting as the DataSource and the field types are being set correctly

Generate DataTable and columns

```
public DataTable FilterData(DataTable datatable, string dataType)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dataType == "MailPreferences")
            {

                var dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Columns.Add("SEQ_ID", typeof(int));                              // SEQ_ID
                dt.Columns.Add("MAIL_PREFERENCE_ID", typeof(string));               // MAIL_PREFERENCE_ID
                dt.Columns.Add("Mail Preference Description", typeof(string));      // MAIL_PREFERENCE_DESC
                dt.Columns.Add("Post", typeof(bool));                               // POST
                dt.Columns.Add("SMS", typeof(bool));                                // SMS
                dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(bool));                              // EMAIL
                dt.Columns.Add("Telephone", typeof(bool));                          // TELEPHONE

                foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(row["SEQ_ID"].ToString(), 
                                row["MAIL_PREFERENCE_ID"].ToString(), 
                                row["MAIL_PREFERENCE_DESC"].ToString(),
                                Convert.ToBoolean(row["POST"]), 
                                Convert.ToBoolean(row["SMS"]), 
                                Convert.ToBoolean(row["EMAIL"]),
                                Convert.ToBoolean(row["TELEPHONE"]));
                }

                return dt;

            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // catch and deal with my exception here
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The above method is being called here and this is where I am having the issue of disabling cells.

```
private void PopulateMailPreferencesGV()
    {
        var dt = FilterData(_cAddPersonWizard.GetMailPreferneces(), "MailPreferences");
        dgvMailPreferences.DataSource = dt;

        dgvMailPreferences.Columns["Mail Preference Description"].Width = 250;
        dgvMailPreferences.Columns["Post"].Width = 50;
        dgvMailPreferences.Columns["SMS"].Width = 50;
        dgvMailPreferences.Columns["Email"].Width = 50;
        dgvMailPreferences.Columns["Telephone"].Width = 75;

        dgvMailPreferences.Columns["SEQ_ID"].Visible = false;
        dgvMailPreferences.Columns["MAIL_PREFERENCE_ID"].Visible = false;


        // not setting the datagridview cell to readonly
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMailPreferences.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxCell))
                {
                    if(((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex]).Selected == false)
                    {
                        ((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex]).ReadOnly = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

When stepping through and looking at the Watch window I can see that the read only properties are being set, however when coming to work with the DataGridView the cells are still active.

I would be grateful if someone could point me in the direction of where this code is wrong or if I need to do something else?

Thanks for your help.

--- Edit 31/05/2017

[image]

The image above shows the grid that I want to work with, the options that are selected are selected by default.

The options that are not selected are to be disabled because these forms of delivery are not possible for the mail type

Comment: My interpretation of this code is that upon population it makes all checkbox cells that or not currently selected read only. You indicated that you wanted only some of the cells readonly what is the criteria for cells that are suppose to be readonly

Comment: it must be `Selected == true` in the last condition, isn't it?

Comment: when stepping through I see that its only making the cells that I need to be readonly, however, when coming to use the datagridview and testing that the checkboxes shoud be disabled they are still active.

Comment: @anatol no, if they are not selected when the grid is loaded then they are to be set to read only

Comment: @SimonPrice you could try setting the bool columns to read only if that is what you were going for. But on till you provide clearer details that would just be a shot in the dark

Comment: @Nkosi if i set it on the columns to encompass everything then yes the columns and cells become read only, however thats not what I am going for.  As stated I only need the colums that are not selected at the time of binding the source to be read only, which is why I am looping through and trying to set it on the cell not the column

Comment: nope, i have revised my comment above

Comment: @SimonPrice, You are going to have to clearly walk me through that process. Between setting the datasource how could they be selected if you are now populating and binding the grid?

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: Ok now I understand. You were using the wrong term. Selected is when you have the cell highlighted. You want cells that already have a value set to true to be read only

Comment: no, its the otherway round, if they are not set to true i want them to be read only

Comment: try `Enable = false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had checked this in a small sample project and this worked for me:

```
// Loop through all the rows of your grid
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvMailPreferences.Rows)
{
    // Loop through all the cells of the row
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        // Check if the cell type is CheckBoxCell
        // If not, check the next cell
        if (!(cell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)) continue;

        // Set the specific cell to read only, if the cell is not checked
        cell.ReadOnly = !Convert.ToBoolean(cell.Value);
    }
}
```

Further you can add an event to track cell changes to activate read only for clicked cells:

```
private void dgvMailPreferences_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)) return;

    DataGridViewCell cell = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

    if (!(cell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)) return;

    cell.ReadOnly = !System.Convert.ToBoolean(cell.Value);
}
```

(Fires after a change was done and the cell was left.)

You can build a sample project with the fiddle from [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) at [Dotnetfiddle](http://%20dotnetfiddle.net/ifZ6Rx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form();
            var dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
            form.Load += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var dt = GetData();
                dgv.DataSource = dt;
                dgv.Columns["Mail Preference Description"].Width = 250;
                dgv.Columns["Post"].Width = 50;
                dgv.Columns["SMS"].Width = 50;
                dgv.Columns["Email"].Width = 50;
                dgv.Columns["Telephone"].Width = 75;
                dgv.Columns["SEQ_ID"].Visible = false;
                dgv.Columns["MAIL_PREFERENCE_ID"].Visible = false;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (cell.Value is bool && (bool)cell.Value == false)
                            cell.ReadOnly = true;
                    }
                }
            };
            Application.Run(form);
        }

        static DataTable GetData()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("SEQ_ID", typeof(int));                              // SEQ_ID
            dt.Columns.Add("MAIL_PREFERENCE_ID", typeof(string));               // MAIL_PREFERENCE_ID
            dt.Columns.Add("Mail Preference Description", typeof(string));      // MAIL_PREFERENCE_DESC
            dt.Columns.Add("Post", typeof(bool));                               // POST
            dt.Columns.Add("SMS", typeof(bool));                                // SMS
            dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(bool));                              // EMAIL
            dt.Columns.Add("Telephone", typeof(bool));                          // TELEPHONE

            dt.Rows.Add(1, "1", "Membership", true, true, true, true);
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "2", "Monthly Newsletter", false, false, true, false);
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "3", "Mothhly Technical Briefing", false, false, true, false);
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "4", "Magazine", false, false, true, false);
            dt.Rows.Add(5, "5", "Branch Mailings", false, true, true, false);
            dt.Rows.Add(6, "6", "Events", true, true, true, true);
            dt.Rows.Add(7, "7", "Qualifications", true, true, true, true);
            dt.Rows.Add(8, "8", "Training", true, true, true, true);
            dt.Rows.Add(9, "9", "Recruitment", true, true, true, true);
            dt.Rows.Add(10, "A", "General", true, true, true, true);

            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will test this in a moment and let you know how i get on

Comment: Hmmm, I used .NET 4.0 wait a second and I downgrade to 2.0

Comment: Checked this with .NET 2.0 and it still works. Which VS version do you use?

Comment: currently using vs2015

Comment: Okay, what exactly don't work? The `foreach` or the event?

Comment: @SimonPrice does that mean that my suggestion did not work?

Comment: @Nkosi correct, yours gives me an error and wont compile, i will need to look at it and see why but i gave a message of the error

Comment: @NikBo the checkboxes \ cells are still not readonly and can be changed

Comment: @SimonPrice I have since updated and fixed that 3hrs ago right after you messaged me about the error

Comment: @Nkosi I will try that now

Comment: @SimonPrice Actually this should and does work. Can you provide [mcve] proving the opposite?

Comment: I cannot supply you the applicaiton where I am having the issue, but I should be able to replicate something for you.

Comment: @SimonPrice Something like https://dotnetfiddle.net/ifZ6Rx should be enough. So we can copy/paste it to a new Windows Forms Application project, run it and see the issue. Btw, you can do the same with the code from my link and see that it works :)

Comment: running your fiddle without making any changes gives me this Compilation error (line 4, col 22): The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Also the .Net version is set to 4.5 where this is a 2.0 application and therefore is already a mismatch for what i need

Comment: @SimonPrice If you copy the fiddle code into a new project, you will see that it works. Don't run the code on the page! Just create a project with .NET 2.0 and copy this code into `Program.cs` and then run the project.

Comment: @NikBo your fiddle works, just dont see how that is doesnt work here

Comment: you might want to update your answer to reflect your fiddle and then i can award the points

Comment: @SimonPrice You mean this from Ivan Stoev? I had added it to the answer.

Comment: I guess Ivan should have set it as an answer himself then...  you get the points by default now

Comment: @SimonPrice Ivan had just build an application which generates a window 
 with controls, which uses my code.

Comment: Indeed I was just supporting this answer (after up voting it) because it was the correct one in my opinion. So glad to see that it got the bounty (and hope the issue has been resolved as well), happy coding to all :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)Rows[Index].Cells["colName"]).ReadOnly = true;
```

Hopefully it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, when populating, if the initial value of the checkbox is false then it should be read only.

Try setting the read only value using the following

```
// not setting the datagridview cell to readonly
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMailPreferences.Rows) {
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
        if (cell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkBoxCell = cell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
            //What is the initial  value in the checkbox
            bool isChecked = checkBoxCell.Value as bool;
            //set to read only if not checked
            checkBoxCell.ReadOnly = !isChecked;                 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error Opperator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type object and bool when looking at value == false

Comment: I will try this now

Comment: still the same issue, checkboxes are still enabled

Comment: All check boxes. does it set the values when you step through the code in debug mode.

Comment: when stepping through the code, it does show that the cells are read only, but thats the symptoms that I was getting in the first place. It looks like its going to set them, but when it comes to use it then it doesnt actually make the cells read only

Comment: @SimonPrice are you changing any properties of the grid after calling `PopulateMailPreferencesGV()` that may be overriding what is being set

Comment: No, once the values are set its not being touched again

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Ok I realised that the fiddle code wasn't yours (I should have read more carefully). I was able to recreate this using the code from your question. I see what the problem is now, it is this line:

```
if(((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex]).Selected == false)
```

> You are testing against 'Selected' which is not what you want, you want to test against the 'Value' of the cell.

If you look at the code in the other answers this is what they show.

**Original Answer: Left for others**

Running your code (fiddle) the checkboxes are indeed readonly although they do not appear grayed out as if they were disabled (which is what I think you are looking for) Can you confirm if you are able to actually check the checkboxes or not?

Unfortunately you can not disable the checkbox directly.

If this is what you want then you have a couple of options, you can either change the BackColor of the cell, which may be sufficient, however this will not actually change the colour of the checkbox itself.

You can also paint the control yourself, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619.aspx) is a microsoft guide to a similar tutorial.

Or you could create a disabled cell and replace the ones that you need with that. It's not too much work, especially when [someone](https://github.com/DigitalGlobe/DGConnect-ESRI/blob/master/GbdxTools/DataGridViewDisableCheckBoxCell.cs) has already done it for you!

Comment: yes i can confirm that I am able to check and uncheck the boxes that should be readonly

Comment: is this using cell.Value and not cell.Selected?